# Не работает autoplay для видео

Tags: видео

Не работает `autoplay` для тега `video`, уже и jQury отключал, писал `autoplay="autoplay"`, и создавал пустую страницу где кроме `video` ничего нету, ничего не помогло и видео не воспроизводится само! Только если добавить `controls`, но автоплея не будет все равно, оно запуститься только после нажатия на него!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nav-CarSoup</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="nav_header"></div>
        <div class="media_header"> <!--Вот начало-->
            <video class="video_header" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls">
                <source type="video/mp4" src="video/cars_video.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class="search_header"></div>
    </header>
    <section></section>
    <footer></footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score 3):

**Никогда не используйте autoplay для видео**, давайте выбор пользователю. Если все же нужно запускать, например на фоне, то используйте JavaScript для управления.

Некоторые браузеры переводя video в режим `muted` по умолчанию после загрузки. Посмотрите в Chrome: `chrome://flags/#autoplay-policy`

[Изменения политики автовоспроизведения](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Я просто добавил muted к видео.

Answer (score 0):

в JSX react тег `video controls autoPlay muted`

в HTML тег `video controls autoplay muted`

обратите внимание — с какой буквы в каждом случае пишется слово play. Вот именно так у меня заработало.